# How to echo "%20" for spaces in a url

Tags: php, html

I'm making links through a php script to files which sometimes have spaces in them. So I'm replacing all instances of a space with %20 and then echoing the html for the link.

But I'm having a problem where it seems to just ignore %20 and add a space instead. If I manually type the URL with %20 for the spaces the file does get found. I've tried using "+" which does show up in the URL, but the url doesn't work and the file is not found.

```
<?php $newfilename = str_replace(" ", "%20", $docs['filename']) ?>

<a href=http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/database/
candidates/".$newfilename;?>><"Filename"></a>
```

So if the filename is "test file.doc" then the url is "mysite.com/database/candidates/test file.doc"... it ignores the %20.

How can I make this work with files with spaces in the name?

Comment: Just use: `urlencode()`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the built in function [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) (or the closely related [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php))

```
$newfilename = rawurlencode($docs['filename']);
```

`urlencode` is used for encoding querystring arguments, which will probably work here since all you have are spaces. However, `rawurlencode` works with the path of a URL, which is what you're using in your example. (the examples given for both in the documentation back that up)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`rawurlencode()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)?

```
<a href=http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/database/candidates/".rawurlencode($newfilename);?>>
    <"Filename">
</a>
```

It is probably a better idea to put the whole URL in as the parameter though:

```
<?php $url = rawurlencode("http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/database/candidates/$newfilename"); ?>

<a href="<?php echo $url;?>">
    <"Filename">
</a>
```